# How do I change Akka and Logback logging level

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback

To change logging level to `WARN`, do I leave `akka.conf` to `DEBUG`:

```
event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
event-handler-level = "DEBUG"
```

and change `logback.xml` to `WARN`? Or should I change both `event-handler-level` to `WARN` and `logback.xml` to `WARN`?

If I leave `event-handler-level` to `DEBUG` and `logback.xml` to `WARN`, my event bus would be over flooded with log events, no?

Comment: I'd recommend mirroring them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event-handler-level` determines what gets posted to the logger actors, and the Slf4jEventHandler will then faithfully forward everything to logback. If you know that the second step will then drop messages to the floor, it would be better to not generate them in the first place. Since the event handler does not distinguish different levels for different “message categories”, you need to set the event handler level to the lowest level your logback.xml is configured to emit.